# Fetching data from data warehouse in correct way

Tags: database, data-warehouse

I am running job weekly to extract data from DW . The problem i am facing is the data in DW is updated every day by deleting and reloading the data for last 14 days from the source . My weekly  job is scheduled to  fetch last week's data  every monday. But because of this updation on DW side , we are missing lot of data .

One solution here could be to run our weekly job to fetch data for (current date- 21 days ) to (current date -14 ) , which will be outside of the window of updation in DW . However in this scenario , we would always have 14 days old data .

Is there any better way to acknowledge this problem so that i don't end up having 14 days old data .

Comment: Why are you extracting data from a DW? If the DW doesn't provide the reports you need then you should get them built.

Comment: On weekly basis you would be synced back to your DW. So if you get the data from last 21 days from the current date you should have latest snapshot of DW and you can  update the target.